# searching for nonalphabetic strings

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search

Hmm. I tried searching for `9-bit` and `"9-bit"` and it looks like StackOverflow just sees "bit" and ignores the "9-".

Is there a way to search verbatim for nonalphabetic characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure when this was fixed, but it has been fixed.

Comment: A new parsing algorithm went live a few weeks ago :)

Answer (score 2):

[Sure!](http://www.google.de/search?q=9-bit+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: Oh, I meant within stackoverflow, but that works in the interim, thanks!